# Call a program from Python that writes to a file - Can I avoid the IO?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

In python, one can use (e.g.) `subprocess.Popen` to run a program and redirect stdout or stderr as you like so that you can process the output.

Can you do this with called programs that write directly to files?

I have a fortran program that writes its results as files (it also writes intermediate results as files).  Right now, I'm calling this program from Python (2.7), waiting for it to complete, and reading the output file in.

But I have to do this a frequently, and in parallel, and the I/O takes a significant fraction of the runtime.

Without modifying the fortran program, which writes directly to a file (not stdout), can I somehow directly capture the I/O from python, sidestepping the writing to disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this without modifying the Fortran program is probably with [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) - the same idea as a pipe, but persistent (not tied to any one process) and visible through the filesystem.

Let's say we have a simple Fortran program:

```
program writer

    integer,parameter :: u=10
    integer :: i
    real    :: x
    open(u,file='output.dat')
    do i=1,10
        x = (i-1)*0.5
        write(u,*) i, x, x**2, x**3
    end do
    close(u)
end program writer
```

Which, when run, provides the desired output:

```
       1   0.000000       0.000000       0.000000
       2  0.5000000      0.2500000      0.1250000
       3   1.000000       1.000000       1.000000
       4   1.500000       2.250000       3.375000
       5   2.000000       4.000000       8.000000
       6   2.500000       6.250000       15.62500
       7   3.000000       9.000000       27.00000
       8   3.500000       12.25000       42.87500
       9   4.000000       16.00000       64.00000
      10   4.500000       20.25000       91.12500
```

We know the output file is going to be `output.dat` (because it's hardcoded, or provided as an option).

We can create a named pipe called output.dat and read to it from another program, and it will behave as if we had piped the output of the existing Fortran program to another command - even though the Fortran program wasn't writing to stdout or stderr:

```
$ rm output.dat
$ mkfifo output.dat
$ awk '{print "Got line: ",$0}' < output.dat &
[1] 69609
$ ./writer
$ Got line:             1   0.000000       0.000000       0.000000
Got line:             2  0.5000000      0.2500000      0.1250000
Got line:             3   1.000000       1.000000       1.000000
Got line:             4   1.500000       2.250000       3.375000
Got line:             5   2.000000       4.000000       8.000000
Got line:             6   2.500000       6.250000       15.62500
Got line:             7   3.000000       9.000000       27.00000
Got line:             8   3.500000       12.25000       42.87500
Got line:             9   4.000000       16.00000       64.00000
Got line:            10   4.500000       20.25000       91.12500

[1]+  Done                    awk '{print "Got line: ",$0}' < output.dat 
$ rm output.dat
```

Awesome - we just had the writing program write to (as far as it knew) its file, and we had `awk` reading from that file, line by line, as it appeared.

So now we can do that launch and reading from within Python:

```
import os
import subprocess

if __name__ == "__main__":

    outfilename = "output.dat"
    os.mkfifo(outfilename,0777)

    i = []
    x = []
    xsquared = []

    writer = subprocess.Popen( "./writer" )

    with open(outfilename,'r') as fortranoutput:
        for line in fortranoutput:
            items=line.split()
            i.append(int(items[0]))
            x.append(float(items[1]))
            xsquared.append(float(items[2]))

    print "Got: i  = ", i
    print "     x  = ", x
    print "     x^2= ", xsquared
```

And running gives:

```
$ python readFifo.py
Got: i  =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
     x  =  [0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5]
     x^2=  [0.0, 0.25, 1.0, 2.25, 4.0, 6.25, 9.0, 12.25, 16.0, 20.25]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. This is exactly what I needed.